# Derivatives of sums and products "isomorphic" to powers of products and sums

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be smooth Real functions.

From basic algebra, any power of a product is a product of powers:

$$(f\cdot g)^n = f^n\cdot g^n,$$

and a power of a sum is given by the [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

$$(f+g)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk f^{n-k}g^k = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}f^{n-k}g^k.$$

And from calculus, we also have the derivative of a sum

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f+g) = f^{(n)}+g^{(n)}$$

and the derivative of a product

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f\cdot g) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk f^{(n-k)}g^{(k)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}f^{(n-k)}g^{(k)},$$

where the superscript parentheses $g^{(k)}$ denote the $k$th derivative of $g$.

So it seems that addition, multiplication, and exponentiation are "isomorphic", in some sense, to multiplication, addition, and differentiation.

> $$\Big(C^\infty\mathbb R,\;+\;,\;\cdot\;,\;\wedge n\Big)\sim\Big(C^\infty\mathbb R,\;\cdot\;,\;+\;,\;\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Big)$$

I know it's not an isomorphism in the strict sense, but I don't know what other word to use. "Relation" is too weak.

Is this useful? Has it been studied before? What exactly is this relation?

[These](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113847/binomial-theorem-like-identities) [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135510/how-is-leibnizs-rule-for-the-derivative-of-a-product-related-to-the-binomial-fo) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997152/why-does-n-time-differentiation-of-product-have-the-same-structure-as-raising) are similar, but they focus on the binomial stuff. This question is focused on the duality between addition and multiplication.

The exponential function looks like it might be useful here; it maps addition to multiplication, but it maps multiplication to exponentiation, not back to addition.

$$\exp(f+g) = \exp(f)\cdot\exp(g)$$

$$\exp(f\cdot g) \neq \exp(f)+\exp(g)$$

(I have no idea how to tag this question.)

Comment: Uhm... Careful there: the algebraic correlations between sum and product are not symmetric. Namely, multiplication is distributive over addition, not the other way around.

Comment: It's a very nice observation. In *Fourier analysis* there's a duality between the operations $f\mapsto x^nf$ and $f\mapsto f^{(n)} $, it might have something to do with it.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path -- I know. That's one of the reasons it's not truly an isomorphism.